# $(function(){.....}); shows Object required error in ie7 and doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-7

My code works in IE7 but with object required error and doesn't work in chrome and firefox. Please help me. Below is my code
The IE7 browser shows error from the start of jquery function, but I'm able to proceed. But in chrome and safari, the submit button and Validate() functions are not working.

```
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
            <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/ChunkFive_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('h1',{ textShadow: '1px 1px #fff'});
            Cufon.replace('h2',{ textShadow: '1px 1px #fff'});
            Cufon.replace('h3',{ textShadow: '1px 1px #000'});
            Cufon.replace('.back');
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate(){
            var Uname=document.getElementById("username")
            if(Uname.value==""||Uname.value==null){
            alert("Enter Your User Name")
            Uname.focus()
            return false
            }
            if(Uname.value.length<6){
            alert("Min-6 characters for your UserName")
            Uname.focus()
            return false
            }
            var pass=document.getElementById("password")
            if(pass.value==""||pass.value==null){
            alert("Enter Your Password")
            pass.focus()
            return false
            }
            if(pass.value.length<6){
            alert("Min-6 characters for your Password")
            pass.focus()
            return false
            }
            return true 
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>User Management</h1>
            <div class="content">
            <div id="form_wrapper" class="form_wrapper">
            <form class="login active" onSubmit="return validate() action="login.php" method="post">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username"/> 
            <span class="error">enter ur email id</span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label>Password: </label>
            <input type="password"  id="password"/><a href="forgot_password.html" rel="forgot_password" class="forgot linkform">Forgot your password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
            <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <form class="forgot_password" onSubmit="return validate() action="forgotpassword.php" method="post">
            <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
            <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <span class="error">enter ur email id</span>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
            <input type="submit" value="Send reminder"></input>
            <a href="index.php" rel="login" class="linkform">Suddenly remebered? Log in here</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            </div>


            <!-- The JavaScript -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            //the form wrapper (includes all forms)
            var $form_wrapper   = $('#form_wrapper'),
            //the current form is the one with class active
            $currentForm    = $form_wrapper.children('form.active'),
            //the change form links
            $linkform       = $form_wrapper.find('.linkform');

            //get width and height of each form and store them for later                        
            $form_wrapper.children('form').each(function(i){
            var $theForm    = $(this);
            //solve the inline display none problem when using fadeIn fadeOut
            if(!$theForm.hasClass('active'))
            $theForm.hide();
            $theForm.data({
            width   : $theForm.width(),
            height  : $theForm.height()
            });
            });

            //set width and height of wrapper (same of current form)
            setWrapperWidth();

            /*
            clicking a link (change form event) in the form
            makes the current form hide.
            The wrapper animates its width and height to the 
            width and height of the new current form.
            After the animation, the new form is shown
            */
            $linkform.bind('click',function(e){
            var $link   = $(this);
            var target  = $link.attr('rel');
            $currentForm.fadeOut(400,function(){
            //remove class active from current form
            $currentForm.removeClass('active');
            //new current form
            $currentForm= $form_wrapper.children('form.'+target);
            //animate the wrapper
            $form_wrapper.stop()
            .animate({
            width   : $currentForm.data('width') + 'px',
            height  : $currentForm.data('height') + 'px'
            },500,function(){
            //new form gets class active
            $currentForm.addClass('active');
            //show the new form
            $currentForm.fadeIn(400);
            });
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            });

            function setWrapperWidth(){
            $form_wrapper.css({
            width   : $currentForm.data('width') + 'px',
            height  : $currentForm.data('height') + 'px'
            });
            }


            $form_wrapper.find('input[type="submit"]')
            .click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            }); 
            });
            </script>
            </body>
```

Comment: use semicolons! A textbox's value can not be null, the check is useless. Finally do you not indent your code? That would help with finding your error.

Comment: Reverted [this suggested invalid edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2000373#./2000373) which changed the meaning of a sentence of the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for classs onSubmit lacks the closing double quote.

```
 <form class="login active" onSubmit="return validate()**"** action="login.php" method="post">
```

That will fix your issue and trigger the event.

Comment: That's a small error.... I've corrected it, but here again it shows error blandly on $function as object required error. But it works in ie7 local system and.shows error on all browsers in the intranet server. Thanks for ur reply

Comment: $form_wrapper.find('input[type="submit"]')
            .click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            });

Comment: the above function was to be removed to make the other scripts work.... now its working fine